# JSONField show specific field in template

Tags: json, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

i have a Rank class and it has a `JSONField` field and example value is `{"Playoff": 10, "Tournament": 15}`

models.py

```
class Rank(models.Model):
    ...
    json=JSONField(default=dict)

class Game(models.Model):
    ...
    status=models.ForeignKey(Status...)
```

now i want to show exact matching field's value so for example, game.gamestatus.name is  `Tournament` 
and i want to show `json.Tournament` value

```
like {{ t.json.{{game.status.name}} }}  (that's wrong i know)
```

How can i do ? what should you suggest to me